# Random text from table mysql

Tags: mysql, database, random, opencart

i made a slider as you can see [here](http://upgradeloja.genesiseries.com/depoimentos/index.php).

That will be like opinions, where my clients will can say something.

Now the code where displays text is:

```
        <div>
            <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E">Paulo Henrique, São Paulo - SP</font></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><font color="#bdbdbd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font></p>
        </div>
```

All is working now, but will be really hard add every opinion here, so what i was thinking?
I can create a mysql and just randomize and call every slider.

I just don't know how to.

I need something like this:

```
[COMMAND TO MYSQL RANDOM MY OPINION]

<p class="depoimento"> PRINT OPINION HERE </p><p class="cliente"> PRINT CLIENT NAME INFORMATION HERE </p>
```

As you can see i have 2 P here, one for opinion and another for client.
I was testing here and i created a mysql DB and a table named: "tdepo" and two columns: Depo and Client

Someone have any idea how i can do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of opinions is small, you can use slow, but reliable version:

```
SELECT opinion_text
FROM opinions
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```

If you want faster version, another solution assumes that table `opinions` has `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column `opinion_id`, and that this column is using *all* values from 1 to number of rows:

```
SELECT opinion_text
FROM opinions
WHERE opinion_id = ceil(random()*
    (SELECT max(opinion_id) FROM opinions))
```

If you have holes, this query may give empty result and you will need to repeat it. But, advantage of it that it is very fast.

Comment: Thans mvp! Well, let's go.
I create a table named opinions and in structure i put:
opinion, type = text
client, type = tinytext

Comment: But where i can put INTEGER PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: You need to add one more field, say `opinion_id`, and make it `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, like in [this example](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html#1_3)

Comment: You mean create a column named OPINION_ID or create a table with auto_increment named OPINION_ID?

Comment: I mean to create just column, not table.